# Find the arrangement around the octagon

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

8 people (call them A, B, C, D, E, F, G, and H) are standing on the vertices

of the colored octagon below, looking toward the center.

[image]

1. E has at least one foot on a secondary color.
2. G is directly across from F.
3. B is on D's right.
4. A, G, and E have both feet in colors having more than 4 letters in their name.
5. The distance from B to G is less than the distance from B to C.
6. G and H straddle two colors.
7. C, F, and H all touch the same color.
8. A is in the center of a primary color.

List the order of the arrangement starting at Red's center and moving clockwise.

The correct answer will show each logical step.

Comment: Which set of primary colors, additive or subtractive? Going just by the RGB values in the image, I'm assuming RGB are primary and Y is secondary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final arrangement is as follows:

> D, F, C, H, A, G, E, B

Step by step explanation:

> The first affirmation I used was 4.
>  [image]
>
>  Then, I chose to use 8, giving me the position of A
>   [image]
>
>  From there, I could figure out the position of both G and E using 1, telling me E was in the middle of green. I then applied every other affirmation using G as a reference (2 and 6)
>  [image]
>
>  After this, I used number 7 to give potential positions for C
>  [image]
>
>  After doing so, I needed to mark the potential candidates for B and D using 3
>  [image]
>
>  I finally used 5, checking the two possibilities for B, and measuring the distance from B to both G and C in both cases
>  [image]
>
>  Given the only pattern that would respect the condition was magenta with C being at the center of blue (see fig. above), I put B and D in their places, as well as all the other missing letters that now could only fit one vertex. Leaving me with the final state
>  [image]

Comment: "E was in the middle of yellow", you mean "green"?

Comment: Colors are hard

Comment: @Auribouros You're so fast! Thanks for adding in all the details. Some of the logic didn't seem to flow, and I see why. Check out the last 4 words of the first sentence of the puzzle and make the necessary corrections to the answer and the logic flow, and this one is yours!

Comment: Longest spoiler ever.

Comment: @JLee Oh my god, I *just* realized indeed, I did understand it correctly I just mixed left and right! Will fix right now!

Comment: @Auribouros Please also change the final answer string at the top of your answer.